# HiveODBC - Error from hive: Internal error processing ExecuteStatement

Tags: odbc, hive

I am connecting Tableau to Hive. It was working perfectly for the last 5-7 days.
But now its stopped connecting to the hive with the below error.
“[HiveODBC] (34) : Error from hive: Internal error processing ExecuteStatement"

here are the logs from hiveserver2

```
    2014-06-23 06:06:19,888 ERROR [pool-5-thread-5]: thrift.ProcessFunction (ProcessFunction.java:process(41)) – Internal error processing ExecuteStatement
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:713)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:949)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1360)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.submit(Executors.java:638)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.ATSHook.run(ATSHook.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1089)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:912)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:907)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runInternal(SQLOperation.java:144)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.run(SQLOperation.java:174)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:231)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatement(HiveSessionImpl.java:212)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatement(CLIService.java:220)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:346)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1313)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1298)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)        
    at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:55)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I just google and found to that a there is memory leak bug. But I am not sure is that in Hive 0.13 version too ? I am using HDP 2.1 with ambari 1.5

Comment: I believe this could be caused due to the system running out of memory to create file descriptors. Can you run `ulimit -a` and post the results? If it's `1024`, I would suggest changing it to `2048`.

Comment: Although, I restored the server and its running ok now. But I doubt the error may occur again.   here is the limit output.

Comment: ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 59900
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 32768
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited

Answer (score 0):

According to the link below, it seems to be a regression in HDP 2.1:
http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/hive-unable-to-create-thread-hdp2-1/

I haven't tried the workqround suggested but restarting hive fixes at least temporary the problem.